# Axis2 maven plugin with xmlbean binding producing unknown symbol innerType and addNew()

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I am trying to build stub from wsdl using axis2 maven plugin.It is generating a stub file with unknown literals innerType and addNew().

I am using below versions
axis2 : 1.5.1
xmlbeans : 2.3.0

stub file extends org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.
I tried to search these literals in my wsdl as well as in xmlbeans library . But i didnt get it.

Any hints where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people facing same problem, 
I changed unwrap flag to false and it started working